# PCJACOBI works but the default PCBJACOBI failed in PETSc

Tags: iterative-method, petsc, preconditioning

I am using PETSc and libmesh to solve a simple linear elastic problem with quite complicated geometry, using linear tetrahedral elements. I am always using the KSP CG as the solver.

I noticed that for certain meshes, the block-Jacobi (`PCBJACOBI`) preconditioner would fail to converge (`DIVERGED_INDEFINITE_PC`) but Jacobi (`PCJACOBI`) works fine. As a beginner in this field, this sounds very strange to me. Could anyone please help provide a hint?

Also, I read on the PETSc website that both Jacobi and the block-Jacobi support parallel processing. Would that mean that it'd be safe for me just to stay with Jacobi, maybe with some loss in performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`pcjacobi`](https://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-current/docs/manualpages/PC/PCJACOBI.html) is a Jacobi preconditioner (also known is point-Jacobi preconditioner). For this preconditioner, you just take the diagonal elements of the matrix and [invert them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preconditioner#Jacobi_(or_diagonal)_preconditioner) for the future use in the iterative solver.

[`pcbjacobi`](https://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-current/docs/manualpages/PC/PCBJACOBI.html) would be a block-Jacobi preconditioner. For block-Jacobi, you don't take individual diagonal entries, but use small matrix blocks that are on the matrix diagonal. Now, you need to "invert them" whatever that means. A properly configured (block size) block-Jacobi preconditioner usually gives better convergence than point-Jacobi. However, preconditioning and iterative solvers are definitely connected to *dark arts*, thus you always can find some counter-examples.

Now, in your case, probably the matrix does not have any zero diagonal entries; thus point-Jacobi works fine. And the way you configure block-Jacobi results in preconditioner featuring non-invertible (or poorly invertible) blocks, leading to the preconditioning problems. I suggest you take a look at the [PETSc example on block-Jacobi](https://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-current/src/ksp/ksp/examples/tutorials/ex7.c.html) to identify your particular issue.

Regarding parallel processing: I would play more with your particular problem set, understand how different iterative solvers, preconditioners, and their parameters influence the convergence before evaluating the effect from parallelization. And ask it as a separate question later.

Comment: Thank you Anton! This is extremely helpful. I will read through the example you shared! :)